# Creating grouping for C# ArcObjects UniqueValueRenderer?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, display, categorized-renderer

Within a C# procedure I am able to successfully render discrete data values using:

```
pValRen.AddValue("A11", fieldName, (ISymbol)pExpressWay);
pValRen.AddValue("A15", fieldName, (ISymbol)pExpressWay);
```

where `pValRen` is a `UniqueValueRenderer()` object, and, the strings `"A11"` and `"A15"` refer to discrete data values.  But, I need to group `"A11"` and `"A15"` together with a single reference value as suggested in the [online help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#iuniquevaluerenderer.htm).

I have attempted to create a group using:

```
pValRen.AddReferenceValue("A15", pValRen.ReferenceValue["A11"]);
```

or

```
pValRen.AddValue(pValRen.ReferenceValue["A11"], fieldName, (ISymbol)pExpressWay);
```

but, both of these approaches result in an error.  How does one construct and use a ReferenceValue for the UniqueValueRenderer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add a value, in your case this would be "A11" and then add the reference value(s), i.E. "A15". In my codesnippet i have an array   `arLiterals` with all items to group:

```
    string sRefV=arLiterals[0];
    pValRen.AddValue(sRefV, sHeading, iSymbol);
    pValRen.set_Label(sRefV, sClassLabel);
    if (arLiterals.Length > 1)
    {
      for (int l = 1; l < arLiterals.Length; l++)
      {
          pValRen.AddReferenceValue(arLiterals[l], sRefV);
      }
    }
```